# how do I list everything that was eliminated by continue and put it in the output

Tags: java, break, continue

I would like to print everything that was done by continue in the console output

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String searchMe = "Look for a substring in me";
        String substring = "sub";
        boolean foundIt = false;

        int max = searchMe.length() - substring.length();

        test: for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
            int n = substring.length();
            int j = i;
            int k = 0;
            while (n-- != 0) {
                if (searchMe.charAt(j++) != substring.charAt(k++)) {
                    continue test;
                }
            }
            foundIt = true;
            break test;
        }
        System.out.println(foundIt ? "Found it" : "Didn't find it");
    }
}
```

// font:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Comment: @OldProgrammer using a label to reference either a conditional or loop statement is not a GO-TO.

Comment: @Leo Tapia Fairly certain he knows it is not _technically_ a GOTO, but it serves a similar purpose in Java (considering goto is a keyword that does nothing in Java), and it should not be used in nearly every possible situation over other methods.

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable approach, but it's not clear what the author is actually asking.

Comment: I'm new to java and would like to help understand what continue does in this labeled code.
this code is from the official oracle documentation

Comment: @OldProgrammer ‘goto’ not supported in java. and this code is not mine, i am learning labeled break

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you would like to print but continue here is basically skipping the rest of the code in the loop and going to the next iteration.

**EXAMPLE**

```
for (int i=1; i<=5;i++){ //loop through 1-5{
    if (i==4){
        continue;
    } 
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Will print 1 2 3 5.

Comment: I understand, that I already know. what I wanted was to print everything that the continue jumped. for example this 5 that was eliminated in its output

Comment: @CarlosMarinho If i understand correctly, you could place `System.out.println(searchMe.charAt(j++) != substring.charAt(k++));` between the if statement and the continue

Comment: @CarlosMarinho it is also important to note that the label makes it so the continue is used for the `for` loop not the `while` loop

Comment: exactly my frend